# Aggregation $match within a $sum

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow use the $match operator within the $sum function for aggregation.

```
{   "$unwind": "$info.avatarInfoList" },
{   "$unwind": "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList" },
{   "$unwind": "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.flat.reliquarySubstats" },
{
    "$project": {
        "name" : "$name",
        "character" : "$info.avatarInfoList.avatarId",
        "artifact" : "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.itemId",
        "statValue" : {
            "$sum": [
                 {"$match" : { "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.flat.reliquarySubstats.appendPropId" : "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL_HURT" } },
                 {"$multiply": [2, {"$match" : { "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.flat.reliquarySubstats.appendPropId" : "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL" } }]}
            ]
        },
    }
},
{ "$sort": { "statValue": -1 }},
{ '$limit' : 30 }
]).to_list(length=None) 
print(data)
```

I want to be able to use the value of the $sum operator within the project fields somehow, I just don't really understand what the right approach would be for this.

Sample Input (may be too long):
https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ixamekaxoq.json

Sample Output:
( 2 * FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL ) + FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL_HURT sorted from highest to lowest for each item.

```
{name: hat, character: Slayer, artifact: 13, statValue : 25.6}
```

Comment: maybe [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is what you need and please add your expected output

Comment: @1sina1 I've went ahead and updated the main post with a sample output. Thankyou!

Comment: Your sample input is not a complete document.  Are there some missing `{` and/or `[`?  Will the `"avatarInfoList"` array only ever have one element?  If there are multiple items in the `"equipList"`, how would you want the output to look?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you for the response, the input code is rather long and confusing which is why i simplified it down to the basic values, however, you can check out the main post now I have attached a link with the proper document I was trying to refer to. It is possible for avatarInfoList to only ever have one element, that is true. If there are multiple items in `"equipList"`, I still want to calc the specific 2*critical + critical_hurt stat for that item. (If the stat isn't there, the value for that stat should be 0, for ex. `(2 * 0) + CRITICAL_HURT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still a few ambiguities about how you want to aggregate your data, but using the full document from [your link](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ixamekaxoq.json), here's one way to produce the output you want.

N.B.: Weapons in the `"equipList"` don't have `"reliquarySubstats"` so they show a `"statValue"` of `null` in the output.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$info.avatarInfoList"},
  {"$unwind": "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList"},
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": 1,
      "character": "$info.avatarInfoList.avatarId",
      "artifact": "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.itemId",
      "statValue": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.flat.reliquarySubstats",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {"$eq": ["$$this.appendPropId", "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL"]},
                  "then": {
                    "$add": [
                      "$$value",
                      {"$multiply": [2, "$$this.statValue"]}
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "case": {"$eq": ["$$this.appendPropId", "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL_HURT"]},
                  "then": {"$add": ["$$value", "$$this.statValue"]}
                }
              ],
              "default": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"statValue": -1}}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f-6p5dc1-VL).

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve, but as mentioned you want to be using [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) here.

like so:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "statValue": {
      "$sum": [
        {
          $cond: [
            { // if this condition is true (prop id = prop critical hurt )
              $eq: [
                  "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.flat.reliquarySubstats.appendPropId",
                  "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL_HURT"
              ]
            },
            { // then use this value for the "$sum"
              "$multiply": [
                  2,
                  "$info.avatarInfoList.equipList.flat.reliquarySubstats.statValue"
              ]
            },
            0 // otherwise use this value for the sum.
          ]
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y6Zi9zWgVUv)

Comment: I want to find the sum of items in reliquarySubstats such that if there is the value "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL_HURT", it's added to the value of 2 * "FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL". Meaning that something with {appendPropId:FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL_HURT, statValue:3} and another item with {appendPropId:FIGHT_PROP_CRITICAL, statValue: 5}, the output of these within the reliquarySubstats field would be (2*5) + 3 = 13